# Unable to pass url through afterLoad function

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor, cucumber

I am trying to get webpage title in nodejs and below code works fine.
I am able to see Title through console.log("Title is - "+webpagetitle)

```html
var afterLoad=require('after-load');

var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
 By = webdriver.By,
 until = webdriver.until;

var chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');

var options = new chrome.Options();
options.addArguments("-headless");

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
 .forBrowser('chrome')
 .setFirefoxOptions(options)
 .build();

 
 driver.get('https://www.google.com/').then(function()
 {
 driver.getTitle().then(function (webpagetitle) {
    console.log("Title is - "+webpagetitle);
    }
 )});
```

But when am trying to use afterLoad like below it's not working.

```html
var afterLoad=require('after-load');

var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
 By = webdriver.By,
 until = webdriver.until;

var chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');

var options = new chrome.Options();
options.addArguments("-headless");

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
 .forBrowser('chrome')
 .setFirefoxOptions(options)
 .build();

   
 
 afterLoad('https://www.google.com/', function (){
   driver.getTitle().then(function (webpagetitle) {
    console.log("Title is - "+webpagetitle);
    }
    )}
    );
```

Error-
Blank webpage is opened and in console Title is blank, see below:

```html
C:\Users\Mohit.Garg\Desktop\Cucumber practice\example6>node test3.js
[20992:20792:0122/144906.947:ERROR:install_util.cc(687)] Failed to read HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\MachineLevelUserCloudPolicyEnrollmentToken: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12422/devtools/browser/a07420ff-c059-44e7-bce2-800e1dfd38f9
Title is -

C:\Users\Mohit.Garg\Desktop\Cucumber practice\example6>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 afterLoad('https://google.com',function(html){
        browser.getTitle().then(function (webpagetitle) {
           console.log("Heyyyyyy title is - "+webpagetitle);
        })
 })
```

No need for function keyword, because `afterLoad` function is already declared in the `after-load` package, you just calling it. Ckeck for usage example [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/after-load)

Comment: Thanks @Lunin for rectifying this silly mistake but my main purpose of using afterLoad is still unresolved, would be great if you can look again, have edited my question. Thanks again.

Comment: @MohitGarg can't find git repository of the `after-load` library, seems it does not exists anymore, probably the problem with `after-load` package itself

Comment: Could be the case but if so they would have obsoleted [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/after-load) anyways thanks.

Comment: I would suggest you to check original `afterLoad` function code first, the code you did provide looks good to me, you also can created your own `afterLoad` function and define it globally